# React.js question: How do I apply multiple classes to a component using a ternary operator?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I want to apply multiple classes to a component using a ternary operator. There is a shared ts theme file that includes the general button styles, but I would like to display their sizes in this particular component differently depending on screen width, so have added locally scoped classes for this too.

[image]

What is the best approach for this?

...tried this, not working:

[image]

...got it working using classNames.

Comment: So there is more than two classes to be applied to the same component?

Comment: as a string :) instead classes.saveButton ` `${classes.saveButton} other-class` `

Comment: Use module like `classnames` or `clsx`. These are built for this purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I usually use a small npm package called `classNames`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames.

It exposes a function that takes a variable number of arguments. If you give strings, they will be basically joined with a space, so you have them all applied:

```
<Button className={ classNames('first', 'second') } ...
```

Will be like doing:

```
<Button className="first second" ...
```

A nice feature that this package has, is that it can take an object where the key is the class and the value is a boolean that indicates whether to add this class or not, something like:

```
<Button className={ classNames({ even: index % 2 === 0, disabled: props.isDisabled }) } ...
```

Now, if `index` is something like `2`, the `even` class is added to the element.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [clsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clsx), I think it's already installed if you use material-ui, and you can see that in material-ui's documentation examples.

```
import clsx from 'clsx';

// Bellow examples are from the clsx npm site:

// Strings (variadic)
clsx('foo', true && 'bar', 'baz');
//=> 'foo bar baz'

// Objects
clsx({ foo:true, bar:false, baz:isTrue() });
//=> 'foo baz'

// Objects (variadic)
clsx({ foo:true }, { bar:false }, null, { '--foobar':'hello' });
//=> 'foo --foobar'
```

Answer (score 0):

Material UI classes are compiled to classname strings, you can chain them with a space between each one :

```
<Button
  classes={{
    root: isDesktop ? `${classes.saveButton} ${classes.secondStyle}` : classes.disabledSaveButton
  }}
>
```

npm package [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) can do this for you in a cleaner way if you need to handle more complex cases.

Comment: This seems like a good solution, however, it's bringing up this error. Any clue why? (new picture attached to the question).

Comment: @AKL012 This is a linter error, this is a correct template string syntax

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use two  different styles files in css directory for Desktop and Mobile and in index file make switch to  export right css.
   For example:  Styles Directory that contains => 2 css files: Mobile,Desktop and in same directory  index.js for export right one.
2. By Using Theme Providers:
   [styled-components](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced)